# Track increase effort in Sprint Backlog

Tags: scrum, agile-project-management, sprint

We are following Agile development methodology. As a SCRUM master, I am maintaining the Sprint BackLog. I want to know what is the best practice to accommodate any increase in effort for a particular task in the middle of a project.

For example, I am doing ABC task and in the starting of the sprint I have estimated that it requires 10 hrs to complete it, but on the second day I realized that it requires 20 hrs, so how will i update the Sprint Backlog.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the remaining work to 20 hours. Scrum is concerned with the actual work remaining, not whether the original estimate was right. That's important, but it's not explicitly part of Scrum.

If this threatens your ability to deliver on your commitment, then you need to discuss solutions with your team and possibly also the product owner. Perhaps:

- A teammate might have a simpler solution.
- Other tasks were overestimated and you can still deliver everything.
- The product owner might decide it's not worth the effort.
- Sprint planning was rushed and the sprint should be declared a failure and restarted.